# Dism option difference: /mount-image vs /mount-wim

Tags: windows-8.1, dism

what is differrence between this two methods of image manipulation of dism from windows 8.1?

```
dism /Mount-Wim:image.wim ...
```

and

```
dism /Mount-Image:image.wim ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/Mount-Image` command also allows you to mount a VHD file to service it (install updates) while the other command only supports WIM files.

> DISM.exe /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\test\images\myimage.vhd /Index:1
>   /MountDir:C:\test\offline /ReadOnly

The reason why both options show up is that the `/Mount-Image` was added in Windows 8, while the original DISM command was introduced in Windows 7. Removing the `/Mount-Wim` would break older scripts which were written for Windows 7 but would still works for Windows 8.

Comment: but Mount-Image also can mount wim-files to service it... so are there other reasons why Mount-Wim exists?

Comment: the reason is COMPATIBILITY. I added a bit more to my answer